# Why do I keep getting Converting HEAP to MyISAM on my mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish-3

We've been having some issues with our MySQL server intermittently. It keeps throwing out a lot of these queries concurrently (thus stacking them up in my processlist). We are using a MyISAM db and connection pooling through Glassfish v3 for a Grails Application.

db_user myhost:35143 db Query 39

```
converting HEAP to MyISAM /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.7 ( Revision: ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
```

We speculate that there are temp tables being created through GORM (the grails ORM) that are causing these queries.  Why do I keep getting Converting HEAP to MyISAM on my mysql server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About the `converting HEAP to MyISAM` message, the following [answer](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,111012,202235#msg-202235) writes:

> This happens when the temporary tables created by MySQL in the intermediate steps of the query processing grow too big to be stored in memory. As far as I know, when doing this MySQL writes temporary MyISAM tables irrespective of the db engine you use (it just a temp table that will be deleted at the end of the query). It is no problem except for the time the process takes.
>
> The simplest solution is to increase tmp_table_size, may be temporarily if you are doing maintenance work. If this is not enough, split in chunks your query using LIMIT and OFFSET and step-up the OFFSET to cover the all table you read in your query.
> If you are reading several large tables in the query and need to limit each of them, do not forget to cover all the combinations of the tables: e.g. if you use TWO tables and want to split each in THREE parts you will need repeating the OFFSET-ted query SIX times with the different combinations of increasing values of OFFSET. A batch file will come at hand to make all of this easier.

So MySQL is creating these in-memory tables (and potentially converting them into temporary MyISAM tables), not Grails. But my understanding is that they may result from too heavy queries.

Comment: Adding: The bit starting with the comment comes out of Connector-J when a new connection is made. (It's in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl#loadServerVariables if you want to go look.)

If you're seeing a lot of them, I'd double-check that connection pooling is working as you expect, and that your MySQL is configured for an appropriate number of connections.

Comment: I still ge tthis message when running a heacy query on a table that is MyISAM. So where does the heap come from?